# Order posts by years

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I have posts (custom post type) on my site.
I would like to create an archive page showing the archived posts ordered by years.
e.g:

2010
 * post 3 comes here
 * post 2 comes here
 * post 1 comes here

2011
 * post 3 comes here
 * post 2 comes here
 * post 1 comes here

with of course link to the post.
I thought it's simple, however I couldnt find anything simple on the web.
it also needs to be hand coded so I can style it easily.

will appreciate any help
Gil

Answer (score 1):

i found this code snippet a couple of days ago. can´t remember where...
copy this snippet in your archive template

```
<?php
                $year_prev = null;
                $months = $wpdb->get_results(   "SELECT DISTINCT MONTH( post_date ) AS month ,
                YEAR( post_date ) AS year,
                COUNT( id ) as post_count FROM $wpdb->posts
                WHERE post_status = 'publish' and post_date <= now( )
                and post_type = 'post'
                GROUP BY month , year
                ORDER BY post_date DESC");
                foreach($months as $month) :
                    $year_current = $month->year;
                    if ($year_current != $year_prev){
                        if ($year_prev != null){?>
                </ul>
                <?php } ?>
                <h3 class="archive"><?php echo $month->year; ?></h3>
                <ul class="archive-list">
                <?php } ?>
                <li>
                <a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/<?php echo $month->year; ?>/<?php echo date("m", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month->month, 1, $month->year)) ?>">
                <span class="archive-month"><?php echo date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month->month, 1, $month->year)) ?></span>
                <span class="archive-count"><?php echo $month->post_count; ?></span>
                </a>
                </li>
                <?php $year_prev = $year_current;
                endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
```

Comment: Hi Markus
First of all, thanks alot! I tried this snippet but it doesn't present links to the posts underneath the current year. it does post the month's instead... I need to simply have a Year and underneath all the posts related to this year. any help?